# gRaphael popup positions

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael

from what I can see, gRaphael only supports 4 positions for placing a popup, `up`,`down`,`left` and `right`, normally this would be enough, but my line graph has limited space, so the popups are cutting off inside of the SVG. My question is, how can I place the popup in say the `up right` (top right), `up left` (top left), `down right` (bottom right) or the `down left` (bottom left) position?

Comment: how about custom tooltip  , like the one I did in the pie chart ? http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/cuaBX/ that way you control everything...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it! :) I am trying to make use of the popups though. Getting those perfect would be #1st prize!

Comment: You will probably want to adjust the positioning of each popup based on the size of the element. Can you please provide a fiddle of your graph with the popups and I'll see what I can do to move them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using qTip, like so...

```
//show the tooltip
showTip(column.node,column.symbols[0].node,"label",tailPos,tipPos);

function showTip(selector,target,content,tailPosition,tipPosition)
{
    $(selector).qtip({
        content: content,
        position: {
            my: tailPosition,   //tip tail position
            at: tipPosition,    //tip body position
            target: $(target)   //position the tip at this element
        },
        show: {
            ready: true //show popup
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-rounded ui-tooltip-dark'
        }

    });
}
```

worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about custom *tooltip* , create a simple `div` and append it to your chart container, like the one I did in the pie chart ?

[Interactive Pie Chart with Tooltip](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/cuaBX/) , That way you control everything...